# remove selected option from drop down list in angular

Tags: angular

I have a page where dropdown list of items is coming. The list is array of object. I want to remove that object from list which have been selected before.
*component.html*

```
    <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" type="number"                      
    class="form-control" formControlName="Id" >
       <option hidden value="" >Please Select Item</option>
       <option *ngFor="let name of getItems"  type="number" [ngValue]="name.Id">
          { name.ItemName }}
       </option>
    </select>
```

*my component.ts file*

```
   ngOnInit(){
       this.service
      .getItemListByRule(this.Id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.getItems = res.payload;
    });
  } 
  onChange(value) {    
     this.getItems.splice(this.getItems.findIndex(item => item.Id === value), 1);
     console.log(this.getItem)
  }
```

I am using splice method to remove selected item from list of array. But it is not working as expected.

Comment: can you please share your code on any platform like (jsfiddle or codepen etc.) so that one can have a look at it and debug it?

Comment: I would not use splice. Use filter to remove the selected item and return the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to not show but can be selected you need attrib as hidden, some like

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <select type="number"
        class="form-control" formControlName="Id" >
           <option hidden value="null" >Please Select Item</option>
           <option *ngFor="let name of items" 
               <!--just simple hidden if is the value select
                   be carefull!, is not equal use "null" to not add the attrib hidden-->
               [hidden]="form.get('Id').value==name.Id?true:null" 
               type="number" [ngValue]="name.Id">
              {{ name.ItemName }}
             </option>
          </select>
    </form>
```

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iw7amk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update** if we has a FormArray

The formArray can be a FormArray of FormControls

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    array: new FormArray([new FormControl(null), new FormControl(null)])
  });
```

Or a FormArray of FormGroups

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    array: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
          id:new FormControl()
         }), 
      new FormGroup({
          id:new FormControl()
         }), 
    ])
  });
```

In any case you need, as usuall when mannage a formArray a getter

```
  get array() {
    return this.form.get("array") as FormArray;
  }
```

If is a FormArray of FormControls, you use `[hidden]="array.at(i).value==name.Id?true:null"`

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="array">
        <div *ngFor="let control of array.controls;let i=index">
            <select type="number"
    class="form-control" [formControlName]="i" >
       <option hidden value="null" >Please Select Item</option>
       <option *ngFor="let name of items" 
            [hidden]="array.at(i).value==name.Id?true:null"
            type="number" [ngValue]="name.Id">
          {{ name.ItemName }}
         </option>
      </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you use a FormArray of FormGroups use `[hidden]="array.at(i).value.Id==name.Id?true:null"`

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="array">
        <div *ngFor="let control of array.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <select type="number"
    class="form-control" formControlName="Id" >
       <option hidden value="null" >Please Select Item</option>
       <option *ngFor="let name of items" 
             [hidden]="array.at(i).value.Id==name.Id?true:null" 
             type="number" [ngValue]="name.Id">
          {{ name.ItemName }}
         </option>
      </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

NOTE: The stackblitz is updated with the three cases

Comment: @neelam, I just update the answer and the stackblitz (it's only take account how "ask" about the control. if is a formArray of FormControls `array.at(i).value` if is a formArray of FormGroups `array.at(i).value.Id`

Comment: what if we have  form array as in below stackblitz link. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fihutj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @neelam I'm having a similar issue with form array. Array.filter doesn't fit since it modifies the actual array. If you've fixed could you please help

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbsncv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) First of all you forgot to assing your result to your array again

change options to

```
 <option *ngFor="let name of getItems"  type="number" value="{{name.Id}}">
    {{ name.ItemName }}
 </option>
```

and in change method assing to your array

```
onChange(value) {   
   this.getItems=this.getItems.filter(x=>x.Id!=value)
}
```

Comment: it is working. but i am not able to see selected option in input box.

Comment: @neelam, you need mark as "hidden", not filter the list of items